# Change the way shorthands are used in the biblatex verbose style

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` with the `verbose` style. I'd like to change the way that it uses shorthands. At the moment, for all first entries it gives the full citation followed by (henceforth cited as [shorthand]). I want to change this in two ways:

(1) I want, in the first entry, the shorthand to appear in square brackets immediately after the long title. I also want the shorthand to reflect the style of the original entry: i.e. if it is an article it would be enclosed in quotes ('Line & Cave') and if it is a book it would be in italics (*Ethics*). So at the moment the working example I give below produces:

> John Malcolm. ‘The Line and the Cave’. In: *Phronesis* 7 (1962), pp. 38-45
>   (henceforth cited as Line & Cave)
>
> Terence Irwin. *Plato's Ethics*. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 1995 (henceforth cited as Ethics)

What I want to achieve would look like this:

> John Malcolm. ‘The Line and the Cave’ [‘Line & Cave’]. In: *Phronesis* 7 (1962), pp. 38-45
>
> Terence Irwin. *Plato's Ethics* [*Ethics*]. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 1995

(2) I want the shorthand to be introduced only if there exists a second citation that uses the shorthand. That is, if a work is cited only once in the text, then no shorthand is introduced.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Malcolm1962,
  author = {John Malcolm},
  title = {The Line and the Cave},
  year = {1962},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {38-45},
  shorthand = {Line \& Cave},
  journal = {Phronesis}
}
@BOOK{Irwin1995,
  author = {Terence Irwin},
  title = {Plato's Ethics},
  year = {1995},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  address = {Oxford},
  shorthand= {Ethics}
}

\end{filecontents}    
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document} 
\cite{Malcolm1962}

\cite{Irwin1995}

\cite{Irwin1995}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following must be done:

- Enable the `citecounter` feature;
- Remove the `shorthandintro` bibmacro from `cite:full`;
- Define a new bibmacro (say, `shorthand:ifcitation:ifmultiplecited`) that will print the `shorthand` field if we're outside the bibliography and the current entry was cited multiple times;
- Add the new bibmacro to the (type-dependend) format of the `title` field;
- Redefine the format of the `shorthand` field, modelled on the original definition of the `title` field.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose,citecounter=true]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
%  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}% DELETED
  }% NEW

\newbibmacro{shorthand:ifcitation:ifmultiplecited}{%
  \ifbibliography{%
  }{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{citecounter}}{1}{%
      \iffieldundef{shorthand}{%
      }{%
        \nopunct\printtext[brackets]{\printfield{shorthand}}%
      }%
    }{%
    }%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{%
  \mkbibemph{#1}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthand:ifcitation:ifmultiplecited}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{%
    \mkbibquote{#1\isdot}%
    \usebibmacro{shorthand:ifcitation:ifmultiplecited}%
  }
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {title}{%
    #1%
    \usebibmacro{shorthand:ifcitation:ifmultiplecited}%
  }

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {shorthand}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {shorthand}{#1}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Malcolm1962,
  author = {John Malcolm},
  title = {The Line and the Cave},
  year = {1962},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {38-45},
  shorthand = {Line \& Cave},
  journal = {Phronesis},
}
@BOOK{Irwin1995,
  author = {Terence Irwin},
  title = {Plato's Ethics},
  year = {1995},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  address = {Oxford},
  shorthand= {Ethics},
}
\end{filecontents}    

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

\cite{Malcolm1962}

\cite{Irwin1995}

\cite{Irwin1995}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, noticed one small irregularity. I have a couple of entries with shorthand fields that haven't been filled yet. In this case, verbose defaults to the author-title (or, if present, shorttitle) for subsequent citations. But with the above the original citation still has square brackets after the title (but empty, [], since there's no shorthand).

Comment: @D.S. Answer updated.